# Maximum Shell Size?

Tags: java

I have some code that dont let the shell (org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell) get larger than specific x and y based on a running thread.
Is there some other solution to this? shlNtc is the name of my shell.

```
    shellSize = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Point s = shlNtc.getSize();
            //System.out.println(s.x);
            //System.out.println(s.y);
            if(s.x > 980)
                shlNtc.setSize(980, 600);
            if(s.y > 600)
                shlNtc.setSize(980, 600);
            display.timerExec(50, this);                
        }
    };
    this.shellSize.run();
```